# Angular 15.5.0 - Google maps Autocomplete

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-api

I'm working on my first project to learn Angular, but I'm stuck from days on the integration of a google map search bar. I've already integrated a google-map and map-markers components, and they work perfectly. Now I wanted to create a component with a bar where I can write my addres, I get some autocomplete advices and when I confirm I get a well formatted address and the coordinates for other operations.
The problem is the compatibility, I tried every tutorial I found, I used @agm/core but it seems to conflict with other components blocking the building, I tried to downgrade the version of this and @types/googlemaps but nothing changed. I tried to use @angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete but same problem, with ngx-google-places-autocomplete I get stuck with the options that are not recognized. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or there are some compatibility issues. Someone can give me some advice or a tutorial that could solve this problem? :)

I can load the package-lock.json if usefull
Thaanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What does your existing code look like? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue.